# In Zustand and Zustood, Persist doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state-management, zustand

In Zustood, I've enabled the "persist" option, which stores data in local storage. However, when I refresh the page, the data is replaced with the initial state, effectively removing the stored data. The documentation lacks a clear example of how this feature should work. Simply setting the data to local storage without retrieving it during hydration (page reload) doesn't achieve the intended purpose of persisting.

My code:

```
const invoiceSlice = createStore("invoice")(
  {
    cardPaymentImagesUploadedPaths: [] as Array<string>,
    form: {
      data: {
        user_name: "",
        user_phone: ""
      },
      isValid: true
    }
  },
  {
    persist: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
));
```